# Parse error Rmd

Tags: r

I was trying to knit my Rmd file and I get this error.

```
Error in parse(text=x,srcfile=src): <text>:5:51: unexpected symbol 4: pred_test = predict(ames.bas,newdata=ames_test,estimator="BMA")5:resid_test=ames_test$price-exp(pred_test$fit) rmse_test
```

It stoped in line 402:

````
```{r}rmse_train = sqrt(mean((na.omit(ames_train$price - exp(pred_train$fit)))^2))
rmse_train
ames_test = ames_test %>% filter(Neighborhood != "Landmrk", Sale.Condition == "Normal") 
pred_test = predict(ames.bas,newdata=ames_test,estimator = "BMA")
resid_test = ames_test$price - exp(pred_test$fit) rmse_test = sqrt(mean(resid_test^2))

resid_test
````

```
How can I resolve this problem? I tried everything that I could find among the answered questions

Comment: Can you post some of your data so your error is reproducible? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](How to make a great R reproducible example?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming it's because you have 2 lines of code on one line.

```
resid_test = ames_test$price - exp(pred_test$fit) rmse_test = sqrt(mean(resid_test^2))
```

Should be

```
resid_test = ames_test$price - exp(pred_test$fit) 
rmse_test = sqrt(mean(resid_test^2))
```

Comment: Of course! Thanks! I was thinking that I made not that trivial mistake.